# stats.isFile() doesn't recognize file from a path

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to recognize a path being a path of a file using `fs.stat` and `fs.lstat`

```
fs.stat('/img/items/item.jpg', function (err, stats) {
  var isDir = stats.isDirectory();
  var isFile = stats.isFile();
  console.log('isDir: ', isDir);
  console.log('isFile: ', isFile);
});
```

However the message says that it is a dir and `isFile` is `false`.

I am missing something here what would be the right way to recognize that the path is a file path?

Appreciate your kind help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your path, it is extremely likely that you are testing an absolute path when you mean to be testing a relative path.

If it is a relative path from the current process working directory, try omitting the initial slash:  `fs.stat('img/items/item.jpg', ...`

If it is a relative path from the file that includes the `fs.stat()` call, use that file's directory as the starting point:  `fs.stat(__dirname + '/img/items/item.jpg', ...`

If it is relative to, say, a docroot for a web server, you will need to get that directory and construct the path from there. The `path` module may help.